# Suffixes on dates (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc)

Tags: ruby, string, date, format

I'm writing a script to add IPTC data to a folder of images. It extracts the date from the EXIF information and adds this into the `'Caption'` IPTC tag.

```
date = iptc["DateTimeOriginal"]
date = date.strftime('%A %e %B %Y').upcase
iptc["Caption"] = '%s: %s (%s)' % [date, caption, location]
```

The script works except the date outputs:

```
Sunday 13 October 2013
```

Ideally, I would like it to output:

```
Sunday 13th October 2013
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're able (and willing) to bring a Ruby gem into the mix, consider [`ActiveSupport::Inflector`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html). 
You can install it with

`gem install active_support`

(you might need `sudo`)

then require it in your file and include `ActiveSupport::Inflector`:

```
require 'active_support/inflector' # loads the gem
include ActiveSupport::Inflector # brings methods to current namespace
```

then you can `ordinalize` integers willy-nilly:

```
ordinalize(1)  # => "1st"
ordinalize(13) # => "13th"
```

You might have to stringify your date by hand, though:

```
date = iptc["DateTimeOriginal"]
date_string = date.strftime('%A ordinalday %B %Y')
date_string.sub!(/ordinalday/, ordinalize(date.day))
date_string.upcase!
```

and you should be on your way:

```
iptc["Caption"] = "#{date_string}: #{caption} #{location}"
```

Comment: Solved, with a slight tweak in the last bit: changing {date} to {date_string} gives the correct output. Thank you very much!

Comment: Right on! My bad - updated accordingly!

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to require the helper from ActiveSupport, perhaps just copy that one specific method doing the job:

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb
def ordinalize(number)
  if (11..13).include?(number.to_i.abs % 100)
    "#{number}th"
  else
    case number.to_i.abs % 10
      when 1; "#{number}st"
      when 2; "#{number}nd"
      when 3; "#{number}rd"
      else    "#{number}th"
    end
  end
end
```

With that method in your script, change your code to:

```
date = date.strftime("%A #{ordinalize(date.day)} %B %Y")
```